# whats the issue with this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to run this query but it gives me exception.

> "At least one object must implement IComparable."

I don't want to order/distinct by my custom object but just by a string (`v.Venue`). However the similar query with a custom object (instead of string), that doesn't implement IComparable, works fine.

here is my query:

```
new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(
     EventsList.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Venue))
     .Distinct()
     .OrderBy(i => i)
     .Select((v, index) => new KeyValuePair<int, String>(index, v.Venue))
);
```

`EventsList` is an `ObservableCollection<EventSchedules>`

Also, I tried breaking the entire query into pieces, but it fails only for this last query:

`Select((v, index) => new KeyValuePair<int, String>(index, v.Venue))`

Comment: What is `EventsList`? You try to order it, but it doesn't implement `IComparable` so it doesn't know how.

Comment: @RGraham its an ObservableCollection<EventSchedules>

Comment: "However the similar query with a custom object (instead of string), that doesn't implement IComparable, works fine." I very much doubt it. How are you expecting two `EventSchedule` objects to be compared for ordering? Were you actually trying to order by venue?

Comment: @RGraham orderby works fine. see my edit,

Comment: @ay89 Just because it's enumerated on that line, doesn't mean it's the `Select` that's at fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after analyzing my query, I didn't want to sort on my Custom Object (EventSchedule) as others suggested. What I wanted to order & distinct is an string. So I rearranged my query as:

```
new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(
EventsList.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Venue))
.Select(p => p.Venue) //added this
.Distinct()
.OrderBy(i => i)
.Select((v, index) => new KeyValuePair<int, String>(index, v))
);
```

Answer (score 5):

`EventList` object has to implement `IComparable` in order to execute `Distinct()` and `OrderBy()` functions. Linq needs to know how to compare instances of `EventList` in order to sort them and remove duplicates.

Comment answer:
You can order by and do distinct by p.Venue. I.e.:

```
new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(
     EventsList.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Venue))
     .GroupBy(p => p.Venue)
     .Select(grp => grp.First()) // These two lines are lambda way to say Distinct.
     .OrderBy(p => p.Venue)
     .Select((v, index) => new KeyValuePair<int, String>(index, v.Venue))
);
```

Or you can implement a custom comparer.

Comment: how can i do that, its an ObservableCollection

Comment: @ay89, yep, but he's not talking about ObservableCollection, but about EventList object.....

Comment: Are we sure it isn't EventSchedules that needs to implement IComparable?

Answer (score 0):

As per LINQ basics ,
If you are using **EventList** you have to implement Icomparable to use **distinct** and **Orderby**.

I am sure your Query is breaking at OrderbY line but it is shows at Next Line